# Loading View Controller from another View Controller inside Container View

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I'm developing an app for iOS.

I want to have a view controller (called child) that appears inside another view in my main view controller (called parent).
I managed to do this by adding a container view which embeds the child view controller successfully.

In my child view controller I have a button that opens another (3rd) view controller.

I want this screen to open within the bounds of the view container - but it opens on a full screen.

Is there a way I can define the view container in a way that all segues inside of it will show inside its bounds?

Comment: Show your code how you load the 3rd controller

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but the purpose was to have it open inside the view container regardless of the way you load the view controller (in my case I use a 3rd party SDK and I have no access to its code) - like iframe in HTML

Answer (score 2):

`definesPresentationContext` - a `UIViewController`'s property that might be helpful here.

> A Boolean value that indicates whether this view controller's view is covered when the view controller or one of its descendants presents a view controller.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621456-definespresentationcontext

Set the child's property to true:

```
childViewController.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Also, before presenting the viewController (3rd), set its modal presentation style:

```
viewControllerToBePresented.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this post. It might help for adding viewcontrollers within bounds.

http://khanlou.com/2015/04/view-controllers-in-cells/